# What's the use of triggering the "update"-event in dotdotdot (the JQuery plugin)?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a Jquery plugin called dotdotdot.[It's homepage is here](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl)

In this page, the author of dotdotdot gives out a example which I can't understand:

> - Need to update the ellipsis manually? Trigger the "update"-event.
>
>   $("#button").click(function() { $("#wrapper").trigger("update");
>     });

I want to know the what the trigger("update") event handler does.

Formally, I thought it will re-truncate the text after you triggered the "destroy"-event. But it seems not true...

So does any one know the function of this "update"-event?

Comment: Without knowing the plugin and the docs I would guess: `update`: update the truncating, e.g. necessary if the width of the container changed. `destroy`: undo the truncating and removing all the functionality of the plugin, which would also removed the functionality of `update`.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. From your answer, I guess that I can not update the ellipsis after using "destroy" because  the "destroy" removes all functionality, including that of the "update". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the container size dynamically you might want to ask the plugin to recalculate the trimming. So, triggering the update event notifies the plugin to do so.